# Is this markov chain converges against $\pi$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Following task:
Given is an markov chain $(X_n)_{n \in N}$ with stochastic matrix
$$ P = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0.4 & 0.6 \\ 0.3 & 0 & 0.7 \\ 0.2 & 0.8 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$

calculate

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{P(X_n = 2 , X_0 = 1)}$
and
$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{P(X_n = 0 , X_0 = 2)}$

The solution from the creater of this task says :

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{P(X_n = 0 , X_0 = 2)} = \pi_1$
and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{P(X_n = 2 , X_0 = 1)} = \pi_2$

And I just don't unterstand there solution, because $P$ is periodically. So we cant say the markov chain converges against $\pi = (\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3) ^T$, or?

Edit: Question can be closed.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the chain is periodic? The chain is not periodic.

Comment: Your are right, i just did not saw it RIP  Question can be closed than. Tank you!

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just trying to understand where the misunderstanding came from. It is strange to say that "you didn't see" that the chain is aperiodic. Most chains are not periodic, so it is strange to assume that this is the case by default, if that is what you did here.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Doesn't the chain have period 1????

Comment: @Croma14 Yes. If the period of a chain is $1$, then the chain is considered to be non-periodic or "aperiodic".

Comment: I think you meant e.g. $X_n=2\mid X_0=1$ and $X_n=0\mid X_0=2$. We would need to know the distribution of $X_0$ to be able to say anything about the probability of e.g. $\{X_n=2\}\cap\{X_0=1\}$.